# Infopath 2007 Form with SQL Query should fill rows in repeating table

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, infopath

OK, I am trying something I think should be simple and I am messing up somewhere.
I want to query a table in SQL. I am doing it in the code here to clarify my question.  I am receiving data back and have no errors.

I want to select from an Employee table based on lastname.  I am querying "Ryan" and I should get 3 rows of data.  I always get one.
What am I doing wrong or over-thinking?  I am still pretty new to Infopath.  In fact, this is my first form. I have comments in the code.
Thanks.

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace loopthru
{
    public partial class FormCode
    {

        public void InternalStartup()
        {
            ((ButtonEvent)EventManager.ControlEvents["btnGo"]).Clicked += new ClickedEventHandler(btnGo_Clicked);
        }

        public void btnGo_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
        {   // References used are:
            //  References:
            //  Microsoft.Office.Infopath
            //  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Infopath
            //  Microsoft.SharePoint   (copy to project from <DRIVE>:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\60\ISAPI)
            //  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Application.Adapter
            //  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Application.Contract
            //  System
            //  System.AddIn.Contract
            //  System.Data
            //  System.DirectoryServices
            //  System.Web
            //  System.XML


            try
            {

                // Get the employee name or the current user.
                string userName = null;

                XPathNavigator navi = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
                string fieldValue = navi.SelectSingleNode("//my:sfield", NamespaceManager).Value;
                //sfield stands for SearchField.

                if (fieldValue != "")
                {
                    userName = fieldValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    userName = this.Application.User.UserName;
                }

                //connect to my Database
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=DataBaseSource1;database=Database;User id=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;");
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

                command.Connection = conn;

                command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, MidInt, LastName"
                + " FROM EmployeeTable "
                + " where LastName ='" + userName + "'";


                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Emps");

                //I may not need this but it is clean.
                SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {

                    rdr.Read();
                    int FirstName = rdr.GetOrdinal("FirstName");
                    int MidInt = rdr.GetOrdinal("MidInt");
                    int LastName = rdr.GetOrdinal("LastName");


                    XPathNavigator nav = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
                    ////This next line is where I think I am having problems.  I know I am doing this part wrong.
                    //// I think I need to iterate through the recordset returned in the DataSet ds "Emps" but have no clue how.

                    XPathNodeIterator rows = nav.Select("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData", NamespaceManager);
                     foreach (XPathNavigator row in rows)
                   //while (rows.MoveNext()) 
                   //// I tried while and foreach.  everything here works except that I get only one record and it jumps out of the loop.
                   //// I should get three rows based on the lastname entry I place in the my:sfield textbox and click btnGo.
                    {

                        if (rdr[FirstName] != null) rows.Current.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:fname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(FirstName));
                        if (rdr[MidInt] != null) nav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:midint", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(MidINt));
                        if (rdr[LastName] != null) nav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:lname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(LastName));


                    }

                }

            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("data could not be read", ex);
            }

        }

//The visual hierarchy for the Main DataSource in Infopath looks like
    //myFields
        //Emp
            //EmpData
                //fname
                //midint
                //lname
        //sfield

//Also: I didn't add a datasource within the Infopath interface - Add Data Connection.  I only did so in the code behind.       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 I had to create a navigator outside my loop I changed it to:

```
XPathNavigator nav = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields    /my:Emp/my:EmpData", NamespaceManager);
            XPathNavigator EmpNewData = nav.Clone();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
```

I needed to write each value out in turn thus:

```
if (rdr[FirstName] != null) EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:fname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(FirstName));
if (rdr[LastName] != null) EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:lname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(LastName));

EmpNewData.InsertAfter(EmpNewData);
```

Oh, and when you get the dupe record:

```
XPathNavigator firstNode = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData[1]", NamespaceManager);
                firstNode.DeleteSelf();
```

If anyone needs the entire code.  I am happy to share.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with SharePoint but your problem might be that you are setting values in your main Navigator (`nav.`) instead of the current row in your empdata (`rows.Current.`) on the second and third lines in your iteration.

```
                if (rdr[FirstName] != null) rows.Current.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:fname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(FirstName));
                if (rdr[MidInt] != null) nav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:midint", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(MidINt));
                if (rdr[LastName] != null) nav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:lname", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(LastName));
```

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I know that Infopath can live outside of SharePoint, but indeed, I am hosting it within XMLFormView on a SharePoint site. If there's a more appropriate forum - I will be happy to post there. Also, my bad.  I was trying some new things and forgot to change it back.  It still doesn't work when I fix that back.

Comment: I figured this all out and I am extending my solution.  To simplify, I had 2 major problems.